# How to schedule cron job to run only once at a specific date (with year) using node-cron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron, node-cron

I'm new to cron and actually not sure if **node-cron** is the right npm package for me.
Basically, I just want to create a scheduled post feature in my app. Where I can set a time to post my content in the future.

So I discovered **node-cron** and was able to play around with it. I can get it to work, but I noticed this kind of scheduling in node-cron is about setting intervals, and your function is set to repeat again and again. Correct me if I'm wrong.

But let's say I'd like to `console.log("Hello World")` on Feb, 24, 2023 and run it only once. If I set that on the **cron string**(not sure what you call it), then I guess I would set it like this:

```
    cron.schedule("* * * 24 Feb *", ()=>{
        console.log("Hello World")
    })
```

There is no option to specify a year as I read on the documentation, so where I can I specify the year? My code above will run every second on every Feb, 24 in any year right? Don't mind "the every second run" on my code above, but what I wanted to do is to specify the exact date and year for it to run, within that specific date only.

I've read about **node-schedule** package where you can pass dates as the schedule, but it seems node-schedule only runs when the script is running?

Comment: I use node-schedule on my applications with PM2 as the process manager, so the scripts keep running. You should give it a try.